# myFile.js detected as register but didn't execute

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, systemjs, jspm

I use `jspm` & `Rollup` or `SystemJS` to build my WebApp via:
`jspm build myFile dist/myFile.js --minify`

When I try to load myFile.js with SystemJS

```
<script src="/jspm_packages/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="/jspm.config.js"></script>
<script>
  // `myFile` is mapped to npm:myFile@1.23.4
  SystemJS.import('myFile').catch(function (e) {
    console.log("Error with SystemJS.import myFile.js", e );
  });
</script>
```

I get the error: `myFile.js detected as register but didn't execute.`

```
(SystemJS) http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/myFile@1.23.4/myFile.js detected as register but didn't execute. Error: 
  ...(call stack)...
Error loading http://localhost:3000/jspm_packages/npm/myFile@1.23.4/myFile.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `jspm build` was used, it means the [result is able to stand alone](http://jspm.io/0.17-beta-guide/static-builds-with-rollup-optimization.html). Also there was no `--format` specified, [the default is umd](http://jspm.io/0.17-beta-guide/static-builds-with-rollup-optimization.html).

`register` is a module format for SystemJS. To fix this, manually set or override the format. Here is an example using `jspm`:

```
// package.json
...
"jspm": {
  ...
  "overrides": {
    ...
    "npm:myFile@1.23.4": {
      "meta": {
        "myFile.js": {
          "format": "global"
        }
      }
    },
    ...
  }
}
```